# convert this join sql query to linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How Can I convert this sql query to linq

```
 select sum(a.Count),b.PeriodDesc from dbo.tbl_Sample a,dbo.tbl_Period b 
 where a.PeriodID=b.PeriodID group by PeriodDesc
```

tbl_Period   -PeriodID,PeriodDesc
tbl_Sample -  ID,Count,PeriodID

Comment: http://www.linqpad.net/ by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari is a good friend

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `YourContext` is generated context and you have navigation property between `tbl_Period` and `tbl_Sample`, than query will look like:

```
   using(var db = new YourContext())
   {
          var result = db.tbl_Sample.GroupBy(p=>p.tbl_Period.PeriodDesc)
          .Select(p => new {p.Key, p.Count()})
          //whateve you want to do ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

please check it

```
var result = (from a in tbl_Sample
group a by a.PeriodDesc into abc                         
join b in tbl_Period on abc.FirstOrDefault().PeriodID equals b.PeriodID    
 select new ModelName {
   SumofCount = abc.sum(m => m.Count), 

   PeriodDesc = b.PeriodDesc 
 }).tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
var joinedTables = from p in listPeriod
join s in listSample on p.PeriodID equals s.PeriodID
select new { p.PeriodDesc, s.Count };

var result = from p in joinedTables
group p by p.PeriodDesc into g
select new { PeriodDesc = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(p=>p.Count)};
```

Ofc you have to change `listPeriod` and `listSample` with the right collection (or table entity)